# Logistic Regression Variable Selection Multiple Variables

Tags: r, logistic, predictive-models

I have a large dataset with 4000 variables and 20000 observations. Most of the variables are a variety of moving averages since I am trying to create a predictive model. I'd like to use logistic regression with the best of these 4000 variables. I know this is an absurd amount and I am looking to trim it down to less than ten or so but am unsure of the best way to do it.

I'm aware that using stepAIC or the like will take forever and I need something that can select variables based on the p value or any other criteria.

Comment: lasso (e.g. `glmnet` package in R) should handle this easily.

Comment: @BenBolker lasso doesn't work well with highly correlated components, does it? And I am assuming that they are highly correlated since he is referring to a variety of moving averages. Wouldn't it then be better to rely on something like elastic net?

Comment: Is your question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199912 perhaps a replacement for this one?

Comment: @Laterow `glmnet` combines the lasso with elastic net.

Comment: Just because no one else has mentioned it: p-values have absolutely nothing to do with building predictive models, and any use of them in decision making is at best a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 2):

That the data are moving averages means they are time series. As noted by @laterow, if you want to find "real" relationships with a target variable that doesn't capitalize on spurious trends in the information (unit roots, cointegration, nonzero means, autocorrelation, etc.), you would be wise to analyze residuals output from some "white noise" process. In other words, getting these 4,000 variables into an HAC (heteroscedastic and autocorrelation consistent) framework should be your next step before running glmnet, lasso or any other variable reduction method.